# Pandas efficiently applying a function that depends on index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a pandas dataframe with a multindex `d, y, b, r, a` and I need to apply a function that makes a subtraction among the elements of the dataframe depending on the index value.

To simplify things I will consider only three indices, `d, y, r`

Index d can take two values `value0` and `value1`. When `d == value0` the index r can only be `"O"`. Instead when `d == value1` r is an integer between 0 and 999. The rest of the indices are common between `value0` and `value1`.

The dataframe can be constructed as

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d_index = [*["value0", "value0"], *["value1" for _ in range(2000)]]

y_index = [*[0, 1], *[0 for _ in range(1000)], *[1 for _ in range(1000)]]

r_index = [*["O", "O"], *[i for i in range(1000)], *[i for i in range(1000)]]

rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)

results00 = rng.uniform(0, 2, 1000).tolist()
results01 = rng.uniform(0, 2, 1000).tolist()

results20 = rng.uniform(0, 6, 1000).tolist()
results21 = rng.uniform(0, 6, 1000).tolist()


variable0 = [1, 2, *results00, *results01]

variable2 = [
    2.5,
    3.5,
    *results20,
    *results21,
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "d": d_index,
        "y": y_index,
        "r": r_index,
        "string0": variable0,
        "string2": variable2,
    }
)

df.set_index(["d", "y", "r"], inplace=True)
```

I need to compute the difference between some columns, such that all indices are the same except for `value0` and `value1`. The results can be obtained through:

```
df.loc[("value1", 0), "dstring0"] = (df.loc[("value0", 0), "string0"]).to_numpy() - (
    df.loc[("value1", 0), "string0"]
).to_numpy()

df.loc[("value1", 1), "dstring0"] = (df.loc[("value0", 1), "string0"]).to_numpy() - (
    df.loc[("value1", 1), "string0"]
).to_numpy()

df.loc[("value1", 0), "dstring2"] = (df.loc[("value0", 0), "string2"]).to_numpy() - (
    df.loc[("value1", 0), "string2"]
).to_numpy()

df.loc[("value1", 1), "dstring2"] = (df.loc[("value0", 1), "string2"]).to_numpy() - (
    df.loc[("value1", 1), "string2"]
).to_numpy()
```

I can deal with this transformation by looping over the `y, b, a` indices and by performing the subtractions above, however it would not be efficient given the large number of observations (around 8 million)

How can I deal with the operations efficiently?

Edit: added a sample dataframe and the expected output. I also realised that the previous function did not work. I kept it below as a reference

Wrong function

```
def deviation(df_slice, df, variables):
    d, y, b, r, a = df_slice.name
    dvars = ["d" + var for var in variables]
    if d == "value1":
        df.loc[(d, y, b, r, a), dvars] = (
            df.loc[("value0", y, b, "O", a), variables].to_numpy()
            - df_slice[variables].to_numpy()
        )

df.apply(deviation, axis=1, variables=['string0','string2'],df=df)
```

Comment: Please provide an example dataset (as dataframe constructor since this is a MultiIndex) and the expected output

Comment: I have updated the post with what you have asked. And I have realised that my function was not working.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is swifter. However, it will only improve your performance by a little bit (2 times):

```
import swifter

df.swifter.apply(deviation, axis=1, variables=['string0','string2'],df=df)
```

Check out [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/do-you-use-apply-in-pandas-there-is-a-600x-faster-way-d2497facfa66) from towardsdatascience.com about better pandas vectorization concepts.